# Messages lost or messages aren't consumed

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I don't know what is happening very well. After I publish a message in a queue, this message is never consumed, but the message is lost from the queue. I wrote many log messages before to publish and when get the consumer. I can see the log messages from the publisher, but I don't see them in the consumer.

Is there any possibility that this happen?

Thanks,

Viviane

Comment: Can you see messages being accumulated via the Rabbit Web Console if you don't run the consumer? Are there other consumers on the consumers tab in the Rabbit Web Console?

Comment: If RabbitMQ can't route a message to a queue, it is dropped. You should be publishing using publisher confirms so that this case is reported back to your application. I'm not sure how this is done using Spring.

Comment: Please tag questions for spring AMQP with [tag:spring-amqp] so the team gets notified - we don't monitor the generic [tag:spring-boot] tag. See [the documentation for configuring publisher confirms and returns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#template-confirms).

Answer (score 0):

Most of messages are consumed, but there are some of them that aren't. I can't simulate the error, it is intermittent. Because of this I can't understand what is happen.

Answer (score 0):

Enable publisher returns as well as confirms; if a message can't be routed you will get a returned message (which will arrive before the confirm).

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#template-confirms).